# Python: traverse directory tree and check if last subdirectory has a file

Tags: python-3.x, directory-structure

I want to check if the last subdirectories in a directory tree have certain files.

For example, if there are following subdirectories that I want to look through:

```
C:\Test Dir\My Dir\ABC
C:\Test Dir\My Dir\Your Dir\XYZ
C:\Test Dir\My Dir\Your Dir\PQR
```

I want to check if ABC, XYZ, and PQR subdirectories has atleast one file, with following pattern:
*Orange*.txt

If say ABC has a file **ABC_Orange_true.txt**, and XYZ, and PQR don't have a file matching the above pattern, I want to get them in a list, as follows:

list = ['C:\Test Dir\My Dir\Your Dir\XYZ', 'C:\Test Dir\My Dir\Your Dir\PQR']

So far I've written the following code, but stuck here:

```
import os

subdir_list = []
txt_list = []
list = []

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk('.'):
subdir_list.append(subdirList)

for fname in fileList:
    file_list.append(fname)
    if '.txt' in fname:
        if 'Orange' in fname:
            txt_list.append(fname)

subdir_list = [i for i in subdir_list if i][-1]
print subdir_list
print txt_list
```

This code gives me the file names, and list of subdirectories as follows:

```
['ABC', 'XYZ', 'PQR']
['ABC_Orange_true.txt']
```

I need help to reach my end result of

`>>list`

`>>['C:\Test Dir\My Dir\Your Dir\XYZ', 'C:\Test Dir\My Dir\Your Dir\PQR']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glob` module is your friend here. Take a look at this https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob
Using it with the `os` module can solve your problem. Something like

```
import glob, os

def findSubDirs(files):
    subDirs = []

    for f in files:
        if os.path.isdir(f):
            subDirs.append(f)

    return subDirs

def findEmptyLeafDirs(path, filename):
    files, dirs = glob.glob(path + "/*"), []

    subDirs = findSubDirs(files)

    if len(subDirs) == 0:
        fileMatches = glob.glob(path + "/" + filename)

        if len(fileMatches) == 0:
            dirs.append(path)

    else:
        for subd in subDirs:
            dirs.extend(findEmptyLeafDirs(subd, filename))

    return dirs

print(findEmptyLeafDirs("path", "file"))
```

should do it.